# Cookie not deleted in IE browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11, session-cookies

in our application when user logs out we set cookie value to blank.
We call invalidate session and set application cookie value as empty

In all browsers cookie gets deleted as value is empty, but in IE browser this session cookie is not getting deleted and value is coming blank, hence user is getting denied page rather than new login page as session is no longer valid.

---

```
private void invalidateSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(CommonUtil.getPlatformConfigProperty("APP_COOKIE_NAME"), "");
    cookie.setDomain(CommonUtil.getPlatformConfigProperty("COOKIE_DOMAIN"));
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    request.getSession().invalidate();
  }
```

---

Comment: If the cookie value that you get from the request is blank or invalid, you can choose to send the user to the login screen appropriately asking him to sign in. Is that an option?

Comment: once user logout - he is taken to a landing page with a hyperlink to application home page. On clicking hyperlink he is taken to login page again to sign in as there is no valid session. But in IE cookie remains and null value hence application always things session is there but due to null value throws access denied.

Comment: Just the mere presence of a cookie would not meant it is a valid session. You would still need to verify the value of the cookie against the server and if it is valid, you should allow the user to continue to use the app. The same thing needs to be done when the cookie is blank. You will recognize that the cookie is invalid (because it is blank) and then send him to the login screen.

Comment: But is it IE behaviour that it doesnt delete cookie when value is empty/null like other browsers